# No swap limit support - docker engine

Tags: docker

Below command gives a warning of *no swap limit support*.

```
$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.09.5
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 
runc version: N/A
init version: v0.18.0 (expected: fec3683b971d9c3ef73f284f176672c44b448662)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-150-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.704GiB
Name: mohet01-ubuntu
ID: 5R7Z:D7DP:LAFK:OEFL:QTBB:TNMS:R36T:52NW:ZDE7:5KSS:RFIF:FOEU
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

---

I have heard of swap space double the size of RAM size amidst installation of Ubuntu OS, but

What does this warning mean, for docker?

Comment: Please check this may be helpful
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408955/379525

Answer (score 2):

Swap limit support allows you to limit the swap the container uses

On Linux:
Edit the /etc/default/grub file. Add or change this value:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

finally, after saving, run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you have the patience, read this article as well:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Comment: This seems doesn't to cover the case with **cgroup_v2**. If I understand correctly, "cgroup_enable=memory" is there to enable **cgroup_v1** memory controller on the system.
Would be nice to know how to do the same for cgroup_v2. Even with cgroup_v2 memory controller in place, docker refuses to work with swap limits. I cry for help...

Comment: Please respect the copyright laws(At least mention the original link)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408955/549129